# Copying a row from one sheet to another and deleting the original data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy the last populated row from one spreadsheet, to the first non populated row of another spreadsheet. And if possible delete the row that was copied from the source spreadsheet.

```
function moveRows () {
  importRange(
    "1PugO3VL8ZkGzA6stYfUkQK4WoU-FfRUBHUzRDTsEbYE",
    "Sheet2!A:Z",
    "1A2buwUnoDYVRILSETTFd_v6XGmrQtsGD-nT4P8Ufl_0",
    "Sheet x!B1"
    );

}

function importRange(sourceID,sourceRange,destinationID,destinationRangeStart) {
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  // console.log(sourceVals);

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());


  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
    destStartRange.getLastRow() + 1 ,
    destStartRange.getColumn(), 
    sourceVals.length, 
    sourceVals[0].length
  );

  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);


};
```

I found this online, but it copies the entire data from one sheet to another. It does the job, but not exactly what I need it to do.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When including content created by someone else, please provide the proper attribution (include a link to the source and name or user handler of the author). Don't include information about yourself in post, you might add that in your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Instead of deleting a row from the original sheet, this will set a row of empty values into the copied range.

Just replace the sheet name of the oriSheet and tarSheet according your spreadsheet, should get the job done.

```
function moveRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const oriSheet = ss.getSheetByName('original');
  const tarSheet = ss.getSheetByName('target');
  const oriRange = oriSheet.getRange(oriSheet.getLastRow(),1,1,oriSheet.getLastColumn());
  const values = oriRange.getValues();
  tarSheet.getRange(tarSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  oriRange.setValues([values[0].map(col => '')]);  
}
```

Just realized that you are working on 2 spreadsheets...

```
const ssid_1 = '1PugO3VL8ZkGzA6stYfUkQK4WoU-FfRUBHUzRDTsEbYE';
const ssid_2 = '1A2buwUnoDYVRILSETTFd_v6XGmrQtsGD-nT4P8Ufl_0';

function moveRow() {
  const oriSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid_1).getSheetByName('original');
  const tarSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid_2).getSheetByName('target');
  const oriRange = oriSheet.getRange(oriSheet.getLastRow(),1,1,oriSheet.getLastColumn());
  const values = oriRange.getValues();
  tarSheet.getRange(tarSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,values[0].length).setValues(values);
  oriRange.setValues([values[0].map(col => '')]);  
}
```

Just add the Spreadsheet IDs into the variables on top and it should work.